# Firebase Algolia Syncing with node.js - Initial import works but updates don't automatically sync

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I have a node app that syncs my Algolia and Firebase databases together and after following the documentation on Algolia's site, I've been able to get the initial import working. However, any time I update an entry in my Firebase database, I'm noticing it's not issuing a reimport of the data.

Here is my code:

```
usersRef.on('child_changed', addOrUpdateUserIndexRecord);

function addOrUpdateUserIndexRecord(dataSnapshot) {

  // Get Firebase object
  var firebaseObject = dataSnapshot.val();

  // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
  firebaseObject.objectID = dataSnapshot.key;

  // Add or update object
  users.saveObject(firebaseObject, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Firebase<>Algolia object saved', firebaseObject.objectID);
  });
}
```

Am I missing something as to why the code is there, but it won't fire when a child is changed?

Comment: If you put a log statement inside of addOrUpdateUserIndexRecord do you see it print?

Comment: Yeah it only happens when I run the script for the first time. If I leave the script running and try to update a property in my Firebase database, it doesn't re-emit the log statement.

Comment: Gotcha. One guess is that somewhere the script is crashing, so it stops listening for changes. Otherwise, have you double-checked that the child is under the usersRef where you expect? Might be worth seeing if child_added or child_removed had any effect too.